# Linking two different views for the same content type

Tags: 8, views, nodes

I have a content type with around 50 fields with three groups A,B and C(grouped in views). I have a view which shows the new content added in table format(limited fields). I do not want the table to be huge so I have created another view - page containing 3 blocks( A- 10 fields, B- 20, C-20) which shows the content according to the group(A,B,C).[image: table view]
Now the analysis result link has to redirect to the second view and show the correct content corresponding to the content added( nid to be the same), but all the links in every row of the table show the same result- the recent most view result. The link to content redirects correctly to the content but I want it to redirect it to the correct view result.
I have to have a unique url for ever anaylsis result link. I prefer doing it the drupal way, so I tried adding relationship-to show results where nid is same, but it required an absolute value(like nid=5). I tried making the page path /{{nid}} too but it did not work. Please help me with the solution.

I followed the solution postyed by prkos. Here is the current progress:

[image: View1]

[image: View2]
[image: View 2 contextual filter]

[image: result/64 page not found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Construct link in the first Views

You need to create the correct link in your first Views yourself.

You will need the ID field for that purpose since that is the information you need for filtering the second Views.

You don't want the ID show in that Field, we need to construct the link that has the ID in it so that it can be passed to the second View as an argument.

When you add the ID Field set its Formatter to **Unformatted** just to make sure you get plain number out of it.

Under `Rewrite results` select **Override the output of this field with custom text** and in the Text area enter the text you want as your link text, something like "More info about this/Analysis", otherwise the text will be the content ID number.

Again under `Rewrite results` select **Output this field as a custom link** and put the path of your second Views path with the token for your ID field. It will look something like this:

`/my-second-views-path/{{ nid }}`

You can check what your token is in the `Replacement patterns` a bit further down the page. You can also use the raw value token.

You can check your configuration is correct by hovering over the text (it should be a link) and seeing in the browser tooltip (usually bottom left of browser viewport) that the link has been constructed correctly.

### Add Contextual ID in the second Views

To make the second Views show only the one correct result when you click on the constructed link in a particular row in the first View you need to make it aware of that number in the link.

This is done by adding a Contextual ID filter in your second View. Contextual filters are under Advanced options, usually on the right in Views configuration.

Configure it with these settings:
`When the filter value is NOT available`
**Provide default value**
**Content ID from URL**
`When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided`
**Specify validation criteria**
Validator: **Content**
Content type **[yourCT]**
Set other options to what makes sense in your case.

You can test that the configuration is correct by entering a known content ID number into Views `Preview` field, it should show only the row with the content with that ID.

The `Path` of the second View should be `/my-second-views-path/%`. The % character there represents the input for the first Contextual filter (the only one in this particular case).

---

Final test is to visit the First View page and click on a link, it should take you to the second Views page and only show one result, the one with the corresponding ID number.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am halfway there. The first view shows the unique urls in the browser tooltip correctly but the second view generates no result. I added the path name of view 2 as result/%{{ nid }} . Also, on what to apply the contextual filter was not mentioned, I applied it on ID. Please tell me where I am wrong. I am attaching screenshots in my post.

Comment: I tested it and the contextual filter works in views preview of view2. But when i actually go to the page by clicking on the analysis result in  view1 the page is not found.

Comment: Your Contextual configuration and link construction seem good (yes it's the Content ID that should be used as Contextual), but the Path setting in your second View should be `/result/%`, without the nid token. The nid token only goes into link construction in Field overwrite. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! How to add the other 2 blocks in the correct result page? I had to make a block tab of them.  While placing the block tab, in the configure block section I added the page display setting as display only on /result/ /result/% but It did not show up.

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) When configuring Blocks Visibility the path wildcard character is `*`, not `%`, so try `/result/*`.

Comment: Thank you so much! @prkos